# Proactively report broken links when visited

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, broken-links

I'm looking for a programmatic/script solution on the web server level (Apache) that allows the system to report broken links whenever it's clicked (e.g. 404 page is opened), probably by sending a notification email to the admin. We use Websphere Application Server. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you proactively use some web service to scan the site and fix broken links before publishing it or fix it once for all? Waiting for someone to click it sounds very passive although it is not difficult to do (just write a script to monitoring the log file for 404).

Comment: There are many links that are external, and we use content management software that is managed by business users, so yeah.